# Is it possible to have a specialization in EER Model that is purely attribute/condition defined

Tags: entity-relationship

In EER modelling is it possible and correct to have a disjoint specialization where none of the sub-classes have any specific attributes(local to them) but are entirely grouped on the basis of a defining attribute.For example we can have a **USER** entity with some attributes of which one is "role".Based on value of role(admin or author or editor) we will have the subclass entities **ADMIN ,AUTHOR and EDITOR**.None of them has any attributed which are only specific to them.**Also please note that the specialization is disjoint and the superclass entity USER has total participation**.
       And if this is possible, can I convert it to relational model by creating a single relation for the superclass entity USER

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and valid to do so if you want to record relationships that are restricted to the subtypes. If you don't have subtype-specific attributes or relationships, there's no point in distinguishing subtypes in the ER model. A simple role attribute on the User is sufficient for queries.

If you define subtypes in the ER model, this converts to a relation per subtype in the relational model.  If you're looking for something like dependent types, you won't find it in the relational model, which corresponds to first-order logic.  ER is even more limited.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But users with different roles in USER table perform different tasks.How to show this information in ER model without using specialization(for example a person with ROLE=AUTHOR will only add news but cannot publish them.It has to be done by a person with ROLE=EDITOR).Also in the book "FUNDAMENTALS OF DATABASE SYSTEMS BY ELMASRI AND NAVATHE" ,it is written that if specialization is disjoint and local attributes are few or none ,we can create a single relation for the superclass and add a type attribute to identify subclass tuples in it.No need for one table per subtype.

Comment: I am really confused here.So I am only trying to understand what to do and what to not.Your help will be really appreciated.Won't the method mentioned in that book work in my case.

Comment: It sounds like you may be mixing run-time behavior and data modeling. Do you want to model/record tasks or permissions in your database?  If you just need to store the role of each user, that's just an attribute, not subtyping in an entity-relationship model.  Note that subtyping in ER and subclassing in OOP have nothing to do with each other.  It sounds like your book is mixing up the concepts.  OOP is for systems modeling / solution space, not information modeling / problem space.